# Download image that requires digest authentication

Tags: node.js, http

I'm writing a nodejs app that downloads image from an url and saves it. I'm downloading the image using `request`module:

```
var request = require('request');
var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
        request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
            //do some error handling here....
        }
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

download('172.30.0.0/img.jpg', 'downim.jpg', function () {
    console.log("image downloaded");
}
```

This works when I'm downloading an image that is available without authentication. But now I need to download an image that is protected with username and password with Digest Auth. So far I came up with this using module `request-digest`:

```
var digest = require('request-digest')('root', 'pass');
digest.request({
    host: '172.30.0.0',
    path: '/',
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {}
}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("digest err: " + err);
    } else {
        //call function to download the image:
        download('172.30.0.0/img.jpg', 'downim.jpg', function () {
            console.log("image downloaded");
        }
    }
});
```

The idea behind this approach is to first GET root of the url which will authorize me with provided usrname/passwd combination and once I'm authorized proceed to download the image. Yet my authorization is failing with `Error: bad request, answer is empty`. Any ideas on what might be wrong here? Or better yet, is there a better approach to download an image with Digest Auth with only one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it working... The only thing this needed was changing request to GET and adding `.auth('root', 'pass', false)` to it. No need to use `request-digest` module

```
var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {

    request.get(uri, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if (res.statusCode === 401) {

            console.log("not authorized");

        }

        request(uri).auth('root', 'pass', false).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    }).auth('root', 'pass', false); 
};
```

Comment: Do you have a full codeset of this?  I've been trying for days to find a library that supports digest auth and have been failing.